# Prevent double-indent

Tags: phpstorm

What's the code style setting to prevent PhpStorm from adding an extra indentation level when pasting arrays from clipboard?

[image: Screenshot]

The most obvious (continuation indent) does not seem to be the one:

[image: Settings]

Comment: Does it work OK if you reformat code (existing or this newly pasted)? What option do you have for `Reformat on paste` setting? In any case: have a look at array settings at `Wrapping and Braces` tab (could be `Align when multiline`)

Comment: @LazyOne 1) "Code/ Reformat code" does not fix it 2) Reformat on paste has "Indent Each Line" (will play with this and report findings if any) 3) All "Align when multine" are unchecked

Comment: @LazyOne Cool, setting "Reformat on paste" to "Indent Block" appears to do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *Editor/ General/ Smart Keys/ **Reformat on paste***:

[image: Reformat on paste: Indent Block]

Setting it to **Indent Block** appears to fix the issue while keeping the auto-format feature working.